# How to change the tab thumbnails/icons depending on user language on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have an custom app (iframe app) on Facebook and a page tab on the homepage for that app.

Is it possible to have different page tabs on the homepage depending on the user language? I can't seem to find information about that but I've seen some pages that show certain tabs if your Facebook language is English, then a different version of those page tabs if I change my user language to French.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you're describing. You can set a default app thumbnail, and you can set it per page, but I don't believe you can target it to specific locales.

Comment: Thanks. I use that for the content of the actual iframe app, but not on the brand page. I'm looking to change the actual tab on the brand homepage under the main banner.

Comment: If it's a tab on a Facebook Page (which is also an iframe), the `signed_request` variable is POSTed to you and you should be able to use it.

Comment: But the tab thumbnail is statically added to the app when you create the app (via Facebook's Developer app).